# How to make a script display and save its own output to a unique filename?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a basic I/O script I'll call `test.sh` with a bunch of various outputs based on a user input.  Basic example is below:

```
echo "Enter username"
read USERNAME
grep $USERNAME /etc/passwd
grep $USERNAME /etc/group
echo "Done"
exit 0
```

I need this script to display and save all the output when run.  I understand how to pipe a single command with tee to display and save into a file such as `sh test.sh | tee new.txt`, but I am lost on how I can make the script itself save its entire output while displaying it when run.

I also want to make the script save as a unique filename every time it is run, with the filename being `USERNAME-DATETIME.rpt`.  I've tried researching around, but all I can find is how to run a script with redirection and piping, but not how to make the script itself save when run.

How do I display and save script output to a unique filename?

Comment: FYI -- all-caps names are used by variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas the relevant POSIX specification guarantees that applications can set arbitrary lowercase names without interfering with behavior of the shell itself or POSIX-specified utilities. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable..

Comment: (btw, `grep $USERNAME` will mean that you find not just `jdoug` but also `jdouglas` -- are you sure that's what you want? Also, due to the lack of quotes, a username with a space can be split into multiple arguments: You'd need to make it `grep "$USERNAME"` to ensure that names are held together and not string-split or globbed; consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ to catch that flavor of issue).

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect all subsequent output (to stdout) from your script with [`exec`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17974.html):

```
exec 1>"/path/to/$USERNAME-$(date -Is).rpt"
```

(Insert it after you get the `USERNAME`.)

If you wish to redirect both stderr and stdout, use the `&` shortcut (bash-only):

```
exec &>"/path/to/$USERNAME-$(date -Is).rpt"
```

Edit: note that `exec 1>file` will redirect all your output to a file. To **also show it on your terminal** (duplicate it), you can combine `exec` redirect with process substitution:

```
exec &> >(tee "/path/to/$USERNAME-$(date -Is).rpt")
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants content to go *both* to the file and to disk. Perhaps `exec > >(tee ...)` might be appropriate? That said, this is certainly on the right path.

Comment: BTW, in terms of the "insert it after you get the username" advice -- I'd actually prompt to stderr, and put the `exec` at the very beginning (well, right after the shebang). A prompt isn't *output*, after all, but is a status-conveying message for human consumption; stderr is entirely appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, I need it to show on the terminal and write to a file, but unfortunately, I got this error: 

tps-report-gen.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
tps-report-gen.sh: line 5: `exec &> >(tee "$USERNAME.rpt")'

exec 1> worked, but for some reason, exec &> >(tee ...) does not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, but at the very beginning of the file, ``USERNAME`` var is undefined; that's why I said to redirect the output only after we know the output location.

Comment: @Eric, are you using bash? And if yes, which version?

Comment: @randomir I am using Webminal.org for this at the moment, GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: @Eric, I'm not familiar with that service, but it should work in the standard bash. However, you can always use the longer version (non-bash specific): ``exec 1> >(tee filename) 2>&1``.

Comment: @Eric, what matters is not just that you're using bash in your interactive session, but that bash is what's being used to interpret your script. If it's started with `sh scriptname`, for instance, that'll run it with `/bin/sh`, not bash (and even if `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`, that'll run it in compatibility mode with restricted syntax availability); it needs to be `bash scriptname`, or a bash shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or `#!/bin/bash`, or similar as appropriate).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hrmm, this is somewhat over my head, but, this is part of an assignment that is forcing us to run the script using `sh scriptname.sh`, so is there no way to get `exec &> >(tee)` to work?  `exec 1>` worked perfectly, and my script ran flawlessly, however, we are apparently meant to make the script display and save, and we have been provided no instruction on how to do this other than `sh scriptname.sh | tee newfile`.  Thank you by the way.

Comment: @Eric, as I said in my previous comment, you can use: ``exec 1> >(tee filename) 2>&1``. Note the ``2>&1`` in the end. It redirects stderr to stdout, after setting a redirect of stdout to a file and terminal.

Comment: @randomir I tried `exec 1> >(tee $USERNAME.rpt) 2>&1` and received the same error as with `exec &> >(tee)`

Comment: @Eric, if your assignment forces you to write for POSIX sh, then you should be tagging your question `sh` instead of `bash`, as you can't use bash syntax for this assignment.

Comment: @Eric, ...btw, it *is* possible to rewrite this answer to work in /bin/sh, but it's a lot uglier (requires using `mkfifo` to generate a named FIFO, starting a copy of `tee` that reads from the FIFO in the background, and only *then* running `exec > yourfifo`. If @randomir hasn't updated this to have a POSIX sh-compliant solution in the next few hours, I'll add my own answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Wow, I executed my script using bash, and much to my surprise...  `exec &> >(tee)` worked flawlessly.  I have notified my instructor that the assignment was flawed, since it says to set up the script in Webminal (a bash client) using `#!/bin/bash`, yet to execute the script using `sh`.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply wrap the code with brackets and redirect it into a unique filename that you generate. (This is for all practical purposes unique!)

```
#!/bin/bash

myuniquefilename="$( cut -c1-8 <( date "+%S%N" | md5sum ))"

echo "Enter username"
read USERNAME
{
    echo "Executing. ..."
    date 
    grep $USERNAME ./etc/passwd
    grep $USERNAME ./etc/group
} > ${myuniquefilename}.out

echo "Done"
exit 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You should consider the [script](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) command:

> NAME
>
> ```
>    script - make typescript of terminal session
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    script [options] [file]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    script makes a typescript of everything displayed on your terminal.
>    It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an
>    interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file
>    can be printed out later with lpr(1).
>
>    If the argument file is given, script saves the dialogue in this
>    file.  If no filename is given, the dialogue is saved in the file
>    typescript.
> ```

1. Just type `script myfile.txt`.
2. Execute whatever shell commands you want.
3. Enter `<Ctl-D>` when you're done.

Voila!  Your session will be written to "myfile.txt".

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking for the script to save a log *itself*, without manual intervention. Invoking `script` is certainly manual intervention.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to [the answer by @randomir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44741387/14122) that works in all POSIX-compliant shells:

```
# note that using "fifo.$$" is vulnerable to symlink attacks; execute only in a directory
# where you trust no malicious users have write, or use non-POSIX "mktemp -d" to create a
# directory to put the FIFO in.
fifo_name="fifo.$$"

mkfifo "fifo.$$"
tee "/path/to/$USERNAME-$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").rpt" >"fifo.$$" &
exec >"fifo.$$" 2>&1 # redirects both stdout and stderr; remove the "2>&1" for only stdout
```

Be sure to `rm -f "fifo.$$"` when your script is finished executing.

---

In the context of your script as a whole, with some other best-practice fixes, this might look like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Enter username: " >&2
read -r username

fifo_name="fifo.$$"
mkfifo "fifo.$$"
tee "/path/to/$username-$(date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").rpt" >"fifo.$$" &
exec >"fifo.$$" # 2>&1 # uncomment the 2>&1 to also redirect stderr

# look only for exact matches in the correct field, not regexes or substrings
awk -F: -v username="$username" '$1 == username { print $0 }' /etc/passwd
awk -F: -v username="$username" '$1 == username { print $0 }' /etc/group

echo "Done" >&2 # human-targeted status messages belong on stderr, not stdout

rm -f "$fifo_name"
```

Note:

- `date -Is` is a GNUism, not available in BSD date, and certainly not guaranteed across POSIX platforms. Passing an explicit format string is thus the safe thing if you don't know which platform your shell will run on.
- `grep` looks for regexes as substrings -- it could find the user `jdouglas` when it's told to look for `jdoug`, or the user `foo1bar` when looking for `foo.bar` (as a dot is a wildcard in regexes). It also could match against information in a different field (the GECOS field with human names, the home directory, etc). It's much safer to tell `awk` to look for your exact string, in the exact field where you could find it.

Comment: This won't work. ``tee`` hangs trying to write to FIFO. You want ``tee`` to read from FIFO (and then duplicate to file and stdout): ``tee filename <"$fifo_name" &``. Also, after you define ``fifo_name``, there's no reason not use it later on.

Comment: BTW, in your expanded example, I would prefer ``grep -Fw "$username" /etc/{passwd,group}`` over ``awk``. It's simpler and probably what OP wants, particularly for the group file (to find all user's groups, not the user group).

Comment: @randomir, I disagree that simpler is the right thing, if it loses semantics that map the query to actual user intent. If there's a user named `home`, a search shouldn't come up with everyone whose home directory is under `/home`. You could well be right about wanting to match memberships, but I'd still want to be more fine-grained.

Comment: I agree with you that simple(r) is no substitute for correct. But here we're just guessing on what's the OP's intent. :) If the intent is to check for the existence of ``$username``, then we're much better off with ``id -u "$username"`` (POSIX-compliant), anyway.